# Netsuite Saved Search - Return a number randomly from given values

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I am just wondering if someone could help me to return a number randomly from given values for a Netsuite Saved Search

For example:
I want to return either one of the 3 values randomly here: 196429,190569,150567

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

First thing that needs to be done here is to return the saved search values and store them in an array. Please try this and let me know how this goes!!

```
1.Define an array like below
var getArray = [];

2.Push the saved search values to the array by looping through the saved search results like below (I am pushing internal id here, you can push any value you want)

for (var i = 0; i < searchResult.length; i++) 
            {
                var id = searchResult[i].getValue({ name: 'internalid'});
                getArray.push(id);
            }

3.The last step would be to generate the random item from the array


var randomGen = getArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*getArray.length)];
log.debug('randomGen',randomGen);
```

Comment: @kim : please mark this answer as correct if this worked for you!